# show lync contacts in vertical bar like facebook, and when any contact is clicked should open as tabbed conversation like facebook

Tags: c#, wpf, lync

I am trying to make a wpf application where I want to integrate lync.
I want to show my lync contacts, just like facebook contacts at extreme right vertical bar, with search functionality if I want to search any employee.
When I want to start any conversation by clicking on that contact, the contact should open like tabbed conversation docked at the bottom, just like in facebook, or similarly if I get any ping from someone it should open as a docked tab at the bottom.
I have not tried any code yet, but I just want to know if this feasible or any alternatives to this approach.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is all doable.

Microsoft have provided a sample set of working WPF controls for use with Lync. For instance, you can drop in a `contact list control` and a `contact search input box control` and be up and running with a searchable contact list with zero coding!

There's a write up on [thoughtstuff](http://thoughtstuff.co.uk/2012/05/microsoft-lyncs-development-secret-its-easy/) and [MSDN has a walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/hh243697%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

There are approximately 20 controls:
[image: Lync SDK controls]

All of the controls can be reskinned, they are basic WPF elements. The SDK has [full details on doing this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378615.aspx).